# When a domain's CNAME is mapped to a subdomain what would the SERVER_NAME be?

Tags: php, dns, hosting, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi-tenant php web app and have already set up my wildcard subdomains which are working as expected. However, I have a tried to point a domain name to my app's server as follows:

A Record: **domainToRedirect.com 123.123.123.123**

CNAME: **www subdomain.example.com**

When I print out my SERVER_NAME variable on my browser, it seems that the CNAME mapping didn't work as expected as I'm getting **domainToRedirect.com** as the output.

It seems the **domainToRedirect.com** is mapping to the A record and not the CNAME.

What I would like is to have a scenario where the **domainToRedirect.com** simply appears to the end user as though they've visited **subdomain.example.com** but of course the URL bar shows that they're on **domainToRedirect.com**

**EDIT 1:**

The reason I need the SERVER_NAME is because I'm using it to determine my customer's account from the records in my mysql database.

I'm using apache as my webserver.

**EDIT 2**

Here's what my vhost file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com *.example.com 
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: which web server are you using? nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is visiting `domaintoredirect.com` (it is what's shown in their address bar), then they're visiting `domaintoredirect.com` and that's that. The browser is sending a request to the server at `domaintoredirect.com` with the `Host` `domaintoredirect.com`, period.

A DNS CNAME is merely an alias for the IP address configuration.

```
CNAME foo.bar example.com
```

This DNS entry says that the *canonical name* of `foo.bar` is actually `example.com`. In other words, when trying to make a request to `foo.bar`, to discover the server's IP address, request the record for `example.com` instead. All it concerns is how the browser will discover the IP address to send the request to; if you're visiting `foo.bar` you're still visiting `foo.bar`, and when visiting `example.com` you're still visiting `example.com`. A CNAME is merely to share configuration information, to point to a different, already existing DNS record instead of repeating the information.

If you want to redirect from one domain to another you need to do it on an HTTP level; DNS is a few levels too low for redirecting HTTP. And you still cannot "mask" a domain; the domain that's in the address bar is the visited domain, period.

Comment: It therefore means that I have to do a check for both the subdomain on my site as well as the client's domain to determine what their account is from my database? Is there a point to having a cname at all if I can just point the client's domain to my website's A record? I'm thinking of the architecture that wordpress or shopify employ to require you to add a cname record.

Comment: If you want to have `domaintoredirect.com` appear in the browser and serve it from your server, then your server needs to be configured to accept and serve requests for `domaintoredirect.com`, yes. Whether it makes any sense to additionally support a client-specific subdomain is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

First, edit your virtual host info, and add `ServerAlias www.subdomain.com` and restart apache.

Second, you have to use `HTTP_HOST` which gives you the host name from the request, instead of `SERVER_NAME` that gives you the virtual host `ServerName` on Apache

Read here: https://serverfault.com/questions/496597/php-fpm-server-name-sub-domains-using-nginx

Comment: Still seems to give me the same value. Do you think the issue at the DNS level? Is my cname even resolving?

Comment: If the problem is with the DNS, you wouldn't be able to reach the site with the subdomain. I think you have to add to apache 'serverAlias' for each domain. right now it reaches your default configuration and I suppose you have only one site in this server

Comment: I don't want to add a serverAlias everytime I have a new domain because it means restarting/reloading apache evertime a new client adds their domain. How can this be done on the fly since all my subdomains are actually working its just the mapping via CNAMe that's failing?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `ServerName` directive?

Comment: I commented it out, did a reload of apache and got the same result as before.

Comment: first: try to restart , and second: test it by making a temporary php code that runs `php_info()` and search for the subdomain you entered in the browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147528/discussion-between-andromeda-and-tamar).